# BlackBerry push client application subscription

Tags: api, blackberry, push

I have few things to be clarified in BlackBerry push client applications. I have developed an push-enabled application which can receive push messages from the sample push initiator application installed on a publicly accessible location (through BIS). I have now run into a question about sending personalized messages to each device. For that matter I need to use subscription API that comes with BlackBerry push SDK. [This question](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/BlackBerry-Push-Development/Confusion-in-sample-client-side-application/td-p/1776667) is similar to what has been posted here, but it contains no information for me. My questions are,

1. I used the registration API for BlackBerry client app registration to receive push messages from PPG. It requires only app-ID, device-port and push URL(not push initiator URL). Client app registers itself when the application UI starts up(this is how I register with push API). Is this all I need to do to get a subscription for that client with push initiator or does client need to contact push initiator directly for a subscription?
2. Why do I need to provide subscribe/unsubscribe URLs in the push initiator application (I don't provide any unsubscribe/subscribe facility in the client push application ) or is there a way to achieve this through application manager/operating system? or do I need to get unsubscribed users from the PushResult object and process them?
3. How does push initiator come to know about clients initially when there is no mechanism for the push client to subscribe with push initiator?
4. Is there a blog post or tutorial describing each and every step involved in the entire communication process apart from the documentation materials provided by RIM?

Currently I am using Push Essentials but might migrate to Push Plus service later(in the distance future).

Kindly appreciate your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so there are 2 things to keep in mind:
1) The BlackBerry Infrastructure (Push Proxy Gateway or PPG) *needs* to have your device listed as subscribed for your specific application ID in order for pushes to be delivered to your device. Subscribing from the device registers it with the PPG and tells the PPG "I would like to allow pushes from this App ID to be delivered to me". If your device is not subscribed to the PPG then your pushes from the initiator will be sent, accepted by the PPG but never allowed to be delivered to the target device.

2) Even if the device is registered with the PPG, how does your server sending the pushes keep track of what devices are registered? This is done by registering with the Push Initiator. The client sample application included with the Push SDK has a mechanism to show how this can be done. As well the server sample is set to receive these requests and add the client to the database so that it can be included for future pushes.

With all that in mind what happens if:
1) The user un-installs the application
2) The user switches devices

In the above cases there needs to be a mechanism to de-register the device from receiving pushes both from the PPG and from your server Push Initiator. Again the client sample application shows how this can be done.