# Unable to Receive Pushes in client application after Registration in BB10 Webworks

Tags: push-notification, blackberry-webworks

My question is similar to [BlackBerry push client application subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087748/blackberry-push-client-application-subscription) but still i have doubts in that ..plz clarify.My doubt is When i tried with sample Push Initiator which comes with Push SDK and Sample Push-enabled application[Push Capture] from github i can Receive Pushes in that sample application.But when i try the same logic in My own client application i am not receiving Pushes..

**Steps I followed:**

1. Registered with Push service and got Confirmation mail with AppID,Password and PPG url.
2. With those details i set to receive Pushes like:Called the create function and createChannel,success callback was called and it returned device token also.
   But still i am not receiving Pushes in my application.Plz help where i am lagging.

**Question:**

How Pushes differentiate the client app and devices while sending Pushes.
NOTE:i used the same AppID which i used for sample app.

Comment: your Quick response will be very helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when i called create function and createChannel,success callback was called and it returned device token also. When i received Push,**onInvoke** event was called and action was bb.action.PUSH which denotes we received a Push..Since i didnot add Notifications to Hub i didnot recognize previously. 
Also we cannot use same AppID for different applications.It will create problem

Comment: Once Notification received,we can add to Hub screen by calling new Notification(title,options);